# Database design for multi-tenant app with flexible organizational structure

Tags: database-design

We're building a multi-tenant app with flexible organization structure where

1. The org structure can have unlimited levels
2. Org structure can change at any point in time

I'm thinking the main org structure can be a self-referencing table like so:

```
+-------+-------------+----------+
| OrgId | OrgName     | ParentId |
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   1   | Runners     | NULL     |
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   2   | FastRunners | 1        |
+-------+-------------+----------+
```

A version table where the structure can change at any point in time, `FiscalYear` field basically just allows future devs to query easily for reports and such. Would it be correct to call this a version table? or perhaps Detail?:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| VersionId | ValidFrom | ValidTo    | FiscalYear |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     1     | 2019-1-14 | 2019-6-31  | 2018       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     2     | 2019-1-14 | 2019-6-31  | 2018       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     3     | 2019-7-1  | 9999-12-31 | 2019       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     4     | 2019-7-1  | 9999-12-31 | 2019       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

And a mapping table so that the version/detail and main table aren't strongly tied together for easy insert and updates:

```
+-----------+-------+
| VersionId | OrgId |
+-----------+-------+
|     1     |   1   |
+-----------+-------+
|     2     |   2   |
+-----------+-------+
|     3     |   1   |
+-----------+-------+
|     4     |   2   |
+-----------+-------+
```

Do you recommend any changes to this structure? Are there any warnings against such a structure? I don't have much experience in self referencing tables with flexible organization in mind so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: @Brian added question.